# How to hide input keyboard on flutter after clicking phone back button in Textfield in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to hide keyboard when tapping phone back button in editing TextField. But when i trying this keyboard closes quickly and after reopening. How to i fix this?  I try this for Nexus 6 and Pixel 2 and same thing.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('page', style: (TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: '--',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

EDIT: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhZe9.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return WillPopScope(
         child: Scaffold(.....),
          onWillPop: () async {
            var currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
              currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
              return false;
            }else{
              return true;
            }
          },
        );
    }
```

Use WillPopScope to close the keyboard on backpress event

Answer (score 0):

We need the code. But I think the autofocus property of your TextField is set to true. You need to change it false.

**After Edit:**
You need to use WillPopScope.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onBackPressed(context),
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('page', style: (TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: '--',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}

Future _onBackPressed(BuildContext context) {
 FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
}
```

Comment: I added suggestions.

Comment: Its not working for me. I want to close keyboard with device back button (under the keyboard) in TextField. I want remove focus from textfield with back button.

Comment: You can follow these suggestions. 

https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/

Comment: I saw this post but its not for device back button its for just clicking outside of textfield and lose focus its useful but not everytime, probably user will try back button of device for lose focus.